# Object from Parse in LocalDatastore with the local id doesn't update

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, parse-platform

I did a search in local Datastore for an object with the local id and try to update one of its attributes, but instead of customizing it it adds a new object in the `localDatastore` when I execute the pin function again.

For example:

```
const query = new Parse.Query("Todos");
query.fromLocalDatastore();
let todos = await query.find()
for(let i=0; todos.length;i++){
  if(todos[i].get("done") == false){
   todos[i].set("done", true);
   todos[i].pin();
  }
}
```